# What is the computational power required for just verifying maybe two transactions

Tags: transactions, transaction-verification

I want to know the amount of computational power required to verify a just a couple of transactions. No mining included, just verification
can it be done with CPU or maybe even phones?

Answer (score 1):

Transactions can be verified as being valid by inexpensive software, such as a cellphone.

Transaction confirmation requires a miner to include the transaction in a block. Confirmation is not done on a transaction-by-transaction basis, so *"how much power to confirm just a couple of transactions"* is not really a good question to ask. Instead you could ask *"How much computational power do you need in order to mine a block?"*, with the understanding that many transactions can be included in a single block.

Comment: so in DAG tech can transaction verification be done through cell phones where users have to verify two previous transactions?

Comment: That would depend on how the specific DAG coin's protocol works, my answer was in reference to the bitcoin network (which is usually assumed the default here, unless otherwise specified). You would need to be more specific about what coin you are asking about.

Comment: yeah my bad, i was talkinng about DAG technology where users in order to make transactions have to verify two previous transactions
So im wondering if phones can carry out such tasks instead of PC's
In DAG each "block" contains only one transaction

Comment: Again, it depends on what is involved in *'verifying a transaction'*. In general, if the coin is designed to be usable on cheap hardware, then I would expect cheap hardware could be used. But ultimately it will depend on what the protocol requires for verification.

Comment: so theoretically it is possible;
by verifying a transaction i meant to avoid double spending

Comment: There's a difference between verifying and confirming.